# Change Field name in a pivottable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table as follows:

[image]

I have made a PivotTable as follows. The PivotTable sums up the `Quantity` for each combination of Product `ID`, `Year` and `Supplier`. It also does an average of the `Price` for each combination of Product `ID`, `Year` and `Supplier`. But the problem is that we know that the `Price` is **always the same** given one combination of Product `ID`, `Year` and `Supplier`. So I want to change the field name `Average of Price` to just `Price`.

I tried to directly modify in the `Field name` in the popup window, but it gave me an alert `PivotTable field name already exists.`.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You cannot use an existing field name. You could however simply add a space to the end of the new name so that it appears the same.

Comment: @Rory indeed, you could write an answer so that i could accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reuse an existing field name. You could however simply add a space to the end of the new name so that it appears the same.